# Calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{in\theta}}{2^n}$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{in\theta}}{2^n}$$

I don't really have any idea where to begin with this one. Maybe use the Taylor series on the top of the fraction? Doesn't seem to help me much though.

Comment: It's just the sum of an infinite (convergent, of course) geometric series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{gathered}
  \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{z^n}}  = \frac{1}
{{1 - z}},\,\,\left( {\left| z \right| < 1} \right). \hfill \\
  \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{in\theta }}}}
{{{2^n}}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( {\frac{{{e^{i\theta }}}}
{2}} \right)}^n}}  = \frac{1}
{{1 - \frac{{{e^{i\theta }}}}
{2}}} = \frac{2}
{{2 - {e^{i\theta }}}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$